# Spark/Scala - processing last 10 notNull observations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, null

I have data collected from sensors coming daily, and from there I need to generate daily report.
The simplified input data is like this:

`case class measurement(Date: String, item: String, value: Integer)`

The report is based on the most recents 10 measurements of each item.
The problem is that we dont have measurement data for all items each day. Some of them might get missed for one day or multiple continuous days. And we are having new items (which haslve never existed in the database) coming every day.

I tried to look at the solution of using Window and sql function last ignoreNulls, but it doesn't look good as I cannot limit the window's size. And it will be inefficient if setting window size to (t0,now)

What I think of now is to maintain a set of FIFO queues (one queue for each item). For every new dataset coming in, I will need to loop through the set, read the data, and push to the corresponding queue. At the same time when a new value is pushed to a queue, the oldest value of the queue is discarded.
This will work with traditional, old day single machine data processing. However I don't know how to make it work with Spark.

Comment: assuming this is a streaming application, You can filter a dataset that you streamed for a particular window and based on boolean expressions returned you can push to a specific queue. Not sure if this was you question.

Comment: Thank you Vijay. Although mine is not a streaming application, but I think that would still work. Let me try and come back.
Thanks!